# How to pass parameter append to the swf file?

Tags: flash

Due to the target website restriction, it only accepts swf file, and I want to pass parameter to this, So I post

```
http://dlc3.sdo.com/FTP/CASMI/26093415/80112692/player.swf?file=http://dlc3.sdo.com/FTP/CASMI/116052946/152822503/Lesson2.mp4&controlbar=over
```

pass the file parameter this way, and This worked before, But now it doesn't, Where do I do wrong?

Comment: This should be working. How do you try to retrieve these parameters?

Comment: Problem solved, I got the answer from the Jwplayer administrator,he gave me another version of swf that works this way

Comment: http://202.100.92.116:8080/FTP/CASMI/26093415/80112692/player.swf?file=http://dlc3.sdo.com/FTP/CASMI/116052946/152822503/Lesson2.mp4&controlbar=over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should to URL encode your params